# shap.Explainer constructor error asking for undocumented positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, shap

I'm using the python `shap` package to better understand my machine learning model. (From the [documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): "SHAP (SHapley Additive exPlanations) is a game theoretic approach to explain the output of any machine learning model." Below is a small reproducible example of the error I'm getting:

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shap
>>> shap.__version__
'0.37.0'
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> 
>>> iris = shap.datasets.iris()
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(*iris, random_state=1)
>>> model = LogisticRegression(penalty='none', max_iter = 1000, random_state=1)
>>> model.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> 
>>> explainer = shap.Explainer(model, data=X_train, masker=shap.maskers.Impute(),
...                            feature_names=X_train.columns, algorithm="linear")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Based on the stack trace, the error appears to occur in the top level function call not within the call to `Impute()`. I have also tried leaving out the `data=` part and this throws the same error. This seems very strange to me since the neither the `Explainer` object's [documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.Explainer.html#shap.Explainer.__init__) nor [source code](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/_explainer.py) mentions any `data` argument (I verified it's from the same package version I'm using):

```
__init__(model, masker=None, link=CPUDispatcher(<function identity>), algorithm='auto', output_names=None, feature_names=None, **kwargs)
```

Any ideas? Is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The init [signature](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/maskers/_tabular.py#L359) of `Impute` is:

```
def __init__(self, data, method="linear")
```

Hence your error. So, instead of:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, data=X_train, masker=shap.maskers.Impute(),
                           feature_names=X_train.columns, algorithm="linear")
```

you should feed `X_train`to masker:

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, masker=shap.maskers.Impute(data=X_train),
                           feature_names=X_train.columns, algorithm="linear")
```

because it's `masker` that takes care of data in the new API.

Unfortunately, even this won't work, because `Impute` masker [implies](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/_linear.py#L83) `feature_perturbation = "correlation_dependent"` and it doesn't [seem ready](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/explainers/_linear.py#L147)

Though, `Independent` masker is working well:

```
import shap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

iris = shap.datasets.iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(*iris, random_state=1)
model = LogisticRegression(penalty="none", max_iter=1000, random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

masker = shap.maskers.Independent(data=X_test)

explainer = shap.Explainer(
    model, masker=masker, feature_names=X_train.columns, algorithm="linear"
)

sv = explainer(X_test)
sv.base_values[0]
```

---

```
array([-5.0060995 , 13.03460398, -8.02850448])
```

and if you happen to have missing data in your dataset you may impute data yourself, according to your preferred imputation strategy, and feed it to `Independent`.